# Can any one tell about the Grid view in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a large amount of data in my database and I would like to display this data in a grid view using Ruby On Rails. The grid view should allow me to update cells and delete rows, similar to the functionality provided by the Grid-view control in ASP.NET.

Does anyone know of similar functionality in Ruby-On-Rails?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at Extjs. your rails controller can provide JSON data to Extjs grid